# Как удалить клон префаба созданный в скрипте. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу что бы при стрельбе на сцене появлялся префаб выстрела, и через промежуток времени он исчез, но получается, как я понял, что я указал ссылку на префаб, и когда я создаю его в сцене он не создает сам префаб с ссылкой, а клонирует его, помогите исправить.[image: Код который относится к снаряду, в методе Attack создал объект и через некоторое время его удаляю, но он не удаляется] [image: В иерархии видно что создался клон префаба]

Comment: Код желательно приводить картинкой, а не скриншотом. Префаб к скрипту вы откуда цепляете, со сцены или с вкладки Project?

Comment: С вкладки Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты уничтожаешь  сам префаб а не его клон, тебе надо назначить переменную с экземпляром объекта.

```
public GameObject enemy;

void Start() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Instantiate(enemy);
    }
}
```

Это из доков Юнити

А вот пример функции для стрельбы:

```
var BombPrefab : Transform;
 function Update() { if (Input.GetKeyDown("x")) { PlantBomb(); } }

 function PlantBomb()
 {
     var bombPos = transform.position + (transform.forward * 2);
     var cloneBomb=Instantiate(BombPrefab,bombPos,Quaternion.identity);
     yield WaitForSeconds(2);
     Explode();
     Destroy(cloneBomb);

 }
```

Comment: Точно, как-то не обратил на это внимание. Только уж тогда стоит запоминать ссылку на объект, которую вернет Instantiate - это и есть созданный объект и удалять созданный объект по этой ссылке.

Comment: Я понимаю о чем вы, у меня не получается перехватить клон префаба, потому что этот клон появляется во время игры, а по завершении игры он просто исчезает как и ссылка на него

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь, вы помогли мне.